# JDeveloper Installation Error

Tags: jdeveloper

I'm trying to install JDeveloper 12c. When I run the installer it gives this error:

"Unsupported platform (unable to determine the startup directory location).
The Oracle Universal Installer failed.  Exiting."

My platform is Windows 7 x64. I tried 32-bit, 64-bit and generic versions of the installer but the result doesn't change. Is there somebody facing the same problem? Or any idea to solve it?

By the way, I forgot to say that I've already tried to run the installer as Administrator but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: No one came accross with the same problem?

Comment: Do you have any other JDev version installed in your machine?

Comment: Yes, I'm using 11g now. But I guess it's not that kind of installation. I installed it when I was using my old laptop but the installation location was my external harddrive. So when I bought a new laptop, tried to run it from the external storage and it worked. I guess if I find an already-installed version of 12c it'll work too. The problem is to start the installation. It can not determine my platform.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your installed  located - make sure there is no space in the directory path.
Also if you are on windows use the windows installer and not the generic one.

Comment: I've tried everything about the spaced path. Moved the installer to the c drive didn't work. Moved the jdk to the c drive and started with the java.exe inside it also didn't work. Tried on other computers also didn't work. Both general and windows installer versions. Maybe the problem is about locale issues. But i also think the problem is about the installer. Not the program itself. As i said in my question, if i find installed binaries for windows x64 maybe it could work.